# How to modify wrapper div error class when using CakePHP with Bootstrap

Tags: css, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap 3.0RC1` with `CakePHP 2.3.6`. Trying to take advantage of those beautiful looking classes like `has-error` and `has-warning` for [validation states](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation), I need to change the default element class `FormHelper` adds to the wrapping div.

So far I'm using this code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
        'label' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
        'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-block'))
    )
)); 

echo $this->Form->input('email'));
```

Which will output this on error:

```
<div class="form-group error">
    <label for="UserEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input name="data[User][email]" class="form-control form-error" type="email" value="a@a.com">
    <span class="help-block">Email already in use.</span>
</div>
```

Everything is just fine, except that I need to change the `error` class in the wrapping div to `has-error`, so new styles are applied to the `label`, `input` and `span`. Couldn't find a clean solution so far.

The ugly solution I thought is to copy `has-error` styles from Bootstrap to the `error` class in my app.

Comment: A slightly less ugly solution is to add your selector for that specific type of error div to your bootstrap's CSS file. That way you're not copying all the style values, you're simply adding your error divs to the existing style definitions.

Comment: Another option would be to use javascript to change those classes from 'error' to 'has-error' upon DOMREADY, though your page will look strange until that time. Not really a clean solution.

Comment: Yeah derek, thanks, I can't really think of the best one to pick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you introspect `FormHelper`, you'll [find in this line](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1cb7e4f0ff48aab4fac2de32dd46904f3444e52a/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1010) "ugly" code that do error magic.

Since original authors did not leave any chance to do this by configuration, I'm suggesting you writing own `BootstrapFormHelper`, and override input function, by changing that single line.

Here is snippet:

```
//inside public function input($fieldName, $options = array())

$out['error'] = null;
if ($type !== 'hidden' && $error !== false) {
    $errMsg = $this->error($fieldName, $error);
    if ($errMsg) {
        $divOptions = $this->addClass($divOptions, 'has-error'); //old string value was 'error'
        if ($errorMessage) {
            $out['error'] = $errMsg;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm already using custom `BootstrapFormHelper`, [here is link to full gist](https://gist.github.com/trajakovic/8376313).

Just copy file to `app\View\Helper`, and add to **ALL** your Controllers this line:

```
public $helpers = array(
  'Form' => array('className' => 'BootstrapForm')
);
```

assuming that you've saved gist as `BootstrapFormHelper.php`.

Answer (score 10):

**SOLUTION I USE:**

Everytime you create a new input, check if there are any errors for that field using CakePhp function isFieldError() and simply append "has-error" class to div just like i did below:

**Just div setting:**

```
'div' => array('class' => "form-group ".($this->Form->isFieldError('username') ? 'has-error' : '')),
```

**Full code for one field:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input(
    'username',
    array(
        'label' => array('text' => 'Username', 'class' => 'strong'), 'placeholder' => "Your Username", 'class' => 'form-control', 
        'div' => array('class' => "form-group ".($this->Form->isFieldError('username') ? 'has-error' : '') ),
        'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'p', 'class' => 'help-block has-error'))
        )
); ?>
```

Comment: This is ugly and I don't like it.  But it's also the only sane way that I've seen to add the proper classes in Cake without resorting to Javascript, so for that I salute you :)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly less ugly solution is to add your selector for that specific type of error div to your bootstrap's CSS file. That way you're not copying all the style values, you're simply adding your error divs to the existing style definitions.

Another option would be to use javascript to change those classes from 'error' to 'has-error' upon DOMREADY, though your page will look strange until that time. Not really a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dereks first answer, adding your styles into the Bootstrap CSS file.

Lines 1590-1611

```
    .has-error .help-block,
    .has-error .control-label {
      color: #b94a48;
    }

    .has-error .form-control {
      border-color: #b94a48;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    }

    .has-error .form-control:focus {
      border-color: #953b39;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
    }

    .has-error .input-group-addon {
      color: #b94a48;
      background-color: #f2dede;
      border-color: #b94a48;
    }
```

You should change this to:

```
    .error .help-bloc, .has-error .help-block,
    .error .control-label, .has-error .control-label {
      color: #b94a48;
    }

    .error .form-control, .has-error .form-control {
      border-color: #b94a48;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    }

    .error .form-control:focus, .has-error .form-control:focus {
      border-color: #953b39;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
    }

    .error .input-group-addon, .has-error .input-group-addon {
      color: #b94a48;
      background-color: #f2dede;
      border-color: #b94a48;
    }
```

Comment: I think I could use this method, easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used CakePHP, but I dare to post the answer here. I think the message element should be able to carry multiple classes like any other element does.

So the simple edit is:

```
'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-block has-error'))
```

I see no reason to copy and paste the css code.

Comment: That does solve the problem of adding the `has-error` class to the `help-block`. But leaves both label and input styling as if no error was present.

Comment: That only adds the `has-error` class to the wrapping span that contains the message; it doesn't touch the wrapping `div` that contains the entire input element set. With proper CSS you shouldn't even need that.

Comment: "'error' =>" is the error triggering to wrap up the error message element in the form class. By theory, it should work, otherwise need some extra code to take care of the problem. Like I said, I have never used CakePHP. I may try to run a quick test myself with this framework later. Thx.

Comment: Having used CakePHP for a long time I can tell you it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-control').parent('.error').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('has-error');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom Helper that is tailored to whatever the CSS framework is. In this case Bootstrap.

```
<?php

App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class UIHelper extends AppHelper
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function textBox($fieldName, $options = array()) {
        $options += array('class' => 'form-control', 'div'=>false, 'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-block')));

        if (isset($options['label'])) {
            if (is_array($options['label'])) {
                $options['label'] += array('class' => 'control-label');
            } else {
                $options['label'] = array('text' => $options['label'], 'class' => 'control-label');
            }
        } else {
            $options['label'] = array('class' => 'control-label');
        }

        $divOptions = array('class' => "form-group has-feedback");
        if (isset($options['div'])) {
            if (is_array($options['div'])) {
                $divOptions += $options['div'];
            }
        }
        $options['div'] = false;                

        $divText = $this->Form->input($fieldName, $options);

        if ($this->Form->isFieldError($fieldName)) {
            $divOptions['class'] = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
            $divText .= $this->Html->tag('span', null, array('class' => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"));
        }

        return $this->Html->tag('div', $divText, $divOptions);
    }

}

?>
```

Then use this instead of the standard `Form` helper

```
echo $this->UI->textBox('email'));
```