# add a class in div after submit on validation error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.0

add a class in div after submit on validation error

my code is:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'text','label' => false, 'pattern' => "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{4,}$",
                                                  'title' => "Minimum 5 letters.", "id" => "name",
                                                  'placeholder' => 'Enter your Name', 'required' => true,)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I want this after form submission ,if validation is failed:

```
<div class="control-group error">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'text','label' => false, 'pattern' => "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{4,}$",
                                                  'title' => "Minimum 5 letters.", "id" => "name",
                                                  'placeholder' => 'Enter your Name', 'required' => true,)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add id to div, then using jQuery you can add class. $("#ID_VALUE").addClass("error");

Comment: I saw examples of what u say, but if there is any conditional way in cakephp?

Comment: Does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112591/how-to-modify-wrapper-div-error-class-when-using-cakephp-with-bootstrap

Comment: you should check out http://parsleyjs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use javascript to add the class.. For example you could do something like

```
<div class="control-group" id="THISELEMENT">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'text','label' => false, 'pattern' => "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{4,}$",
                                                  'title' => "Minimum 5 letters.", "id" => "name",
                                                  'placeholder' => 'Enter your Name', 'required' => true,)); ?>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
document.getElementById("THISELEMENT").className += " error";
</script>
```